# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::Sessions#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I use a nav bar (using devise on rails; included in my dashboard.html.erb) that works fine when logged in; however when wanting to use it in all pages and including it in the application.html.erb, I get this error: *ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::Sessions#new*

additional info: "*No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"devise/users"}*"

this is my route.rb:

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'dashboard#index'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
```

How should I implement this in Rails following DRY? (am new to rails)

This is my navigation bar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand"><%= Rails.application.class.parent_name %></a>
    </div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to 'Dashboard', root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Users', controller: 'users' %></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><p> You are logged in as <%= current_user.email %></p></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
        <li><%= link_to edit_user_registration_path do %><strong><%= current_user.first_name %></strong><% end %></li>
    </ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using wrong arguments for `link_to` helper here:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Users', controller: 'users' %></li>
```

try this one:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Users', users_path %></li>
```

or, if you would like to point actual controller:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Users', controller: 'users', action: 'index' %></li>
```

More info about `link_to` available [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

Yes, sure, you can do the next:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to 'Dashboard', root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Users', controller: 'users' %></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><p> You are logged in as <%= current_user.email %></p></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
<% else %>
    # do somethid else
<% end %>
```

Comment: partially, now next error appears; will need to make menu items conditional to having signed in. suggestions? Found it: if user_signed_in?

Comment: Yes, you're right. You can use `user_signed_in?` helper

Comment: Is this the way to do this? Or asked  differently - the entries menu depend on being signed in but also on (to be implemented (don't yet know how) authorizations (CRUD on objects etc)? Any suggestions to do this without repeating?

Comment: I see. Unfortunately there is no way to render that menu without repeating of conditions. You can move all that menu into partial and then render just a partial. That approach will keep your layout clean and it's also some kind of DRYing